# c# mvc reroute request to different server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application which is a mesh of a few different servers and 1 server is the front-end server which handles all request external incoming requests.

So some of these request will have to be passed along to different servers and ideally the only thing I want to change is the host and Uri fields of these request. Is there a way to map an entire incoming request to a new outgoing request and just change a few fields?

I tried something like this:

```
// some controller
public HttpResponseMessage get()
{
    return this.Request.Rewrite("192.168.10.13/api/action");
}


//extension method Rewrite
public static HttpResponseMessage Rewrite(this HttpRequestMessage requestIn, string Uri) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
    HttpRequestMessage requestOut = new HttpRequestMessage(requestIn.Method, Uri);
    requestOut.Content = requestIn.Content;

    var headerCollection = requestIn.Headers.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
    foreach (var i in headerCollection)
    {
        requestOut.Headers.Add(i.Key, i.Value);
    }

    return httpClient.SendAsync(requestOut).Result;
}
```

The issue I am having is that this has a whole slew of issues. If the request is a get `Content` shouldn't be set. THe headers are incorrect since it also copies things like host which shouldn't be touched afterwards etc.

Is there an easier way to do something like this?

Comment: You want some load balancing software. I wouldn't recommend trying to do this kind of thing yourself in code. It's much better to get an off the shelf package.

Comment: @Liam can't do it. This is a simplified use case. In the real world there is some authentication behind the scenes.

Comment: load balancer or reverse proxy. It's a pretty standard setup and most COTS products should be able to cope with authentication, including passing tokens along or whatever. Microsoft ISA is one, integrates well with AD etc.

Comment: @Adyson can it also rewrite request content in certain ways? Can it also dynamically redirect to different uri based on a certain header?

Comment: IIS can rewrite URIs based on headers I think - there's a rewrite module. I dunno about ISA server, it can do a lot of useful things, but I don't know all the possibilities. I'm sure you could read about it in detail though. As for fudging the request content, I don't know what the reason is for doing this but my instinct would be to let the receiving application see the real request and then decide what to do with it, but you may have other reasons. I don't know if those tools can modify content or not off the top of my head, but again, it's one to research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this in C# code for a Silverlight solution once. It was not pretty.

What you're wanting is called **reverse proxying** and **application request routing**.

First, reverse proxy solutions... they're relatively simple.

Here's [Scott Forsyth](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis) and [Carlos Aguilar Mares](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr/) guides for creating a reverse proxy using web.config under IIS.
Here's [a module](https://github.com/kveretennicov/iisproxy) some dude named Paul Johnston wrote if you don't like the normal solution. All of these focus on IIS.

Non-IIS reverse proxies are more common for load balancing. Typically they're [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) based or proprietary hardware. They vary from free to expensive as balls. *Forgive the slang.*

To maintain consistency for the client's perspective you may need more than just a reverse proxy configuration. So before you go down the pure reverse proxy route... there's some considerations.

The servers likely need to share [Machine Keys](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755177(WS.10).aspx) to synchronize view state and other stuff, and share the [Session Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) too.

If that's not consistent enough, you may want to implement session stickiness through [Application Request Routing](https://dotnetcodr.com/2013/06/24/web-farms-in-net-and-iis-part-3-application-request-routing-arr/) (look for Server Affinity), such that a given session cookie (or IP address, or maybe have it generate a token cookie) maps the user to the same server on every request.

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote a simple but powerful reverse proxy for asp.net / web api. It does exactly what you need.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/SharpTools/SharpReverseProxy

Just add to your project via nuget and you're good to go. You can even modify on the fly the request, the response, or deny a forwarding due to authentication failure.

Take a look at the source code, it's really easy to implement :)